# How to customize JAXB binding when generating XSD from Java using Apache CXF cxf-java2ws-plugin

Tags: java-8, jaxb2, java2wsdl

I'm trying to use the Apache CXF cxf-java2ws-plugin version 3.1.6 to generate XSD files from JAXB-annotated Java classes

I need to customize the cxf-java2ws-plugin so that it generates an XSD containing xsd:date types when it encounters Java classes containing Java 8 LocalDate type attributes

I'm sure I need to create a JAXB bindings file but how do I configure the plugin to use it when generating XSD?

There are plenty of examples of how to customize the JAXB binding when generating Java classes from XSD but I'm going the other direction